# Measuring 2D embedded objects in 3D space

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry

Looking at a sphere, a flat surface and a saddle-shaped surface, can we measure or prove all aspects of them, and determine which of them has, in any small region on it, positive curvature, (the sphere), negative curvature, (the saddle-shaped surface) or zero curvature (the flat surface)?

Comment: Are you allowed to look at them from any direction or just one direction?

Comment: You can look at them from any direction

Comment: No you cannot tell if a space is connected or compact simply by determining if it is locally connected or locally compact.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You seem to be imposing some kind of unstated constraint on our knowledge about the surface, but it's impossible for me to guess what kind of constraints you might have in mind.